# WCF Service parameters changed in .NET 2.0 client

Tags: wcf

I created a WCF service that exposed a method that has one paramater:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
}
```

The service has two endpoints defined (wsHttpBinding and basicHttpBinding) so that it would be compatable with older clients.

The service runs just fine in a .NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5 client app.  However, when I create a .NET 2.0 client, the GetData method requires 2 parameters: an integer (expected) and a bool parameter called valueSpecified (unexpected).  I never defined the second parameter.  Why is this happening and how can I get rid of the second parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since value types can't be null (in latter versions of .net framework there is no `Nullable<T>`) VS besides to generate additional parameter to give you ability to not specify value type, you can call your service method like this.

```
service.GetData(val,true);
```

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184245/vs2003-web-reference-for-a-wcf-service-has-extra-idspecified-parameter) post, where John Saunders suggest to add `[DataMember(Required = true)]` attribute in the property.

Comment: This isn't quite the same question as the one you linked to. In this case the client is .NET 2.0, which does include the Nullable<T> class. However the solution still applies.

Answer (score 1):

The exact same question has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531886/wcf-consumed-as-webservice-adds-a-boolean-parameter).

Another way to avoid the extra boolean parameter to be generated on the client proxy when using .NET 2.0 is to switch to **RPC-style enconding** in the service contract (the default for both WCF and ASMX is Document Style).
This way the **XmlSerializer** on the client will make sure that **the parameter always appears in the SOAP requests** since it's part of the SOAP 1.1 specification, which is enforced when using the RPC-Style encoding.

In WCF you can specify the encoding style using the DataContractFormat attribute, either at the service or at the operation level.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [DataContractFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Rpc)]
    string GetData(int value);
}
```

More information on the differences between RPC Style and Document Style encoding in SOAP can be found [here](https://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/c018da90-0201-0010-ed85-d714ff7b7019).

In any case please consider carefully the implications of changing the contract of your services, since it can potentially break compatibility with any existing clients.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually remove the valueSpecified property from  GetData operation within your proxy class.

Comment: This would be a viable workaround only if the client proxy would never have to be regenerated in the future. Otherwise it would be a pain to go through all the generated method signatures to remove the extra parameter every time.